# Email failure delivery

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I already know the answer to my question, but I need to point to a reputable source to back up my claim, so I'm asking you to please describe what you think about the situation in simple terms.

My concrete question is not why the delivery fails, but what is the relation between info@xxxx.xx and association@yyyyyyy.yy

This is the case:

When sending email to info@xxxx.xx after a few days you get back an email with the following contents:

```
This is the mail system at host mail.xxxx.xx.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<association@yyyyyyy.yy> (expanded from <info@xxxx.xx>): host
    mailstore1.europe.secureserver.net[68.178.213.243] refused to talk to me:
    421 p3plibsmtp02-12.prod.phx3.secureserver.net CMGW Temporarily rejected.
    Reverse DNS for ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZ failed. IB108  <http://x.co/srbounce>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just an explanation, in simple terms, what is happening. Specifically what the two email addresses have to do with each other, so that a person not familiar with email servers can understand what's going.on.

Comment: https://itegy.com/en/help-list/workspace-email/what-does-my-email-bounceback-mean states that `421 Temporarily rejected. Reverse DNS for this IP failed. IB108` means `The IP address attempting to send mail does not have reverse DNS setup, or the DNS lookup failed. Verify the sending IP address has reverse DNS setup before resending the email.`

Comment: If you are not the person that is expected to be/get familiar with email servers, an appropriate next step would be to *send mail to your postmaster* as suggested in the report already. If you have not been instructed how to do so, a good starting point would be to reach out to the person/department that had done the initial setup so you could even see this report.

Comment: Are you an admin of `mail.xxxx.xx` (the *postmaster* as they are called in this context)? This person is who needs to be asked as why your email to `info@xxxx.xx` was attempted to be delivered to `association@yyyyyyy.yy` instead and why it then failed to deliver it with this error message. They are the only reputable source. For now your *only* source of information what is happening is *the error message itself*: the server that supposedly was in charge of processing the message (as obtained from the DNS MX record for the target domain) shown you this error instead, and this is all you know.

Answer (score 1):

The email server you are using to send the email is missing the proper reverse DNS record (IP address to domain name mapping).

You need to contact the hosting provider of the email server and add a proper reverse DNS entry that matches the forward DNS entry (domain name to IP address mapping).

Comment: *I need to point to a reputable source* ... would you consider yourself such a reputable source :p